# Joda Time get date from Year + WeekOfYear + DayOfWeek

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Is it possible with Java lib JODA Time to create a date from

- Year
- Week Of the Year (1 to 52 or 53, depending)
- Day Of Week (1 to 7)?

Java has a Calendar function that can calculate it (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setWeekDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 dt = dt.withYear(2015);
 dt = dt.withWeekOfWeekyear(10);
 dt = dt.withDayOfWeek(3);
```